# Does this question belong here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'd like to post a question, but not sure that I should post it either here or Space Exploration.SE

*Why an asteroid doesn't make a sonic bang while entering the atmosphere?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's physics question, so that belongs on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!